# Performance Center API to upload script

Tags: httpclient, performance-testing, multipart, loadrunner

I'm developing a Java tool using HttpClient to programmatically upload a VuGen script to Performance Center. What my tool do are:

1. Authenticate and save session cookie - /LoadTest/rest/authentication-point/authenticate
2. Upload the script - /LoadTest/rest/domains/[MyDomain]/projects/[MyProject]/Scripts
3. Log out - /LoadTest/rest/authentication-point/logout

http://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.53/api_refs/Performance_Center_REST_API/Performance_Center_REST_API.htm#scripts.htm

Authenticate and Log out step are working correctly. Namely, I can get session cookie from authentication and set cookie to be expired when logging out. However, at the upload script step, I always get HTTP 401 error. This is an error message:

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
>
> You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the
> credentials that you supplied.

This is what I sent to the Performance Center server.

```
POST http://[PC-Host]/LoadTest/rest/domains/[MyDomain]/projects/[MyProject]/Scripts HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Content-Length: 31367
Host: [PC-Server]
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_111)
Cookie: LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY=1y8TbNawvT976BENi4oT1hW6_dCMwcz-eohdFDqWpfIXsW2tUMYHZuHZbUBg9wFQwFnQgfetx5I2EvCfaA5y-g..; QCSession=NjA3NTY5O0JWK0ZjSExzWStwTFZPd2xZSXZ5VlEqKjtQQyBSRVNUIEFQSSBDbGllbnQ7IDsg
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

--_NK2aWTiwhT6VV0TIxkUIaHRx0GhDBZ2LOsY8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="xml"
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<Script xmlns="http://www.hp.com/PC/REST/API"><TestFolderPath>Subject\DEV\abc</TestFolderPath><Overwrite>true</Overwrite><RuntimeOnly>true</RuntimeOnly><KeepCheckedOut/></Script>
--_NK2aWTiwhT6VV0TIxkUIaHRx0GhDBZ2LOsY8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="abc.zip"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

## binary of zipped vugen script ##
--_NK2aWTiwhT6VV0TIxkUIaHRx0GhDBZ2LOsY8--
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. XML encoding was to to blame.
I also moved to requests toolbelt to have more control on the multipart structure.

Comment: Are you the original poster?

Comment: Curious, as this functionality to save to performance center is built into VUGEN

Comment: No, I'm not the original poster. I posted a "me too, but with python" comment over there and then commented that "xml encoding was to blame". But it seems that I'm confused of the threading of the answers. Or something. Sorry about that.
Oh, i see now: "deleted from review 2 days ago". that explains why the comment chain makes no sense. It might be best to delete the XML-related comment as well